# Calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{\cos(2x)}-\sqrt{1+x\sin(x)}}{\tan^2\frac x2}$

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{\cos(2x)}-\sqrt{1+x\sin(x)}}{\tan^2\frac x2}$$

I need to calculate this limit  but I don't know what to do for to get out this indeterminate.

I make:

1. $\sqrt{\cos(2x)}-\sqrt{1+x\sin(x)} = \sqrt{\cos(2*0)}-\sqrt{1+0\sin(0)} = \sqrt{\cos(0)}-\sqrt{1+x\sin(0)} = \sqrt{1}-\sqrt{1} = 0 
   $
2. $\tan^2\frac{x}{2} = \frac{0}{2} = 0$

then, $\frac{0}{0}$

I want to get out the $tan^2\frac{x}{2}$.

Comment: Please, write your function using MathJax formatting and show us what you've tried to solve this problem. However today I felt kind enough to write the function in place. Correct it if it doesn't reflect what you meant.

Comment: I not knew to use the MathJax, but I made what I can.

Comment: @Juliana You can't evaluate limits by simply plugging in $0$ to the formula because $0/0$ is undefined. You have to manipulate the function so you can see what the limit would be as you approach $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{\cos(2x)}-\sqrt{1+x\sin(x)}}{\tan^2\frac x2}\\[2em]
= \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{\cos(2x)}-\sqrt{1+x\sin(x)}}{\tan^2\frac x2} \frac{\sqrt{\cos(2x)}+\sqrt{1+x\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{\cos(2x)}+\sqrt{1+x\sin(x)}}\\[2em]
=\lim_{x\to 0^+} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(2x)}+\sqrt{1+x\sin(x)}}\ 
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\cos(2x)-1-x\sin(x)}{\tan^2\frac x2}\\[2em]
=\frac{1}{2}\ 
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\cos(2x)-1-x\sin(x)}{\tan^2\frac x2}
$$
provided the remaining limit exists, but it can be handled using l'hopital or $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$.

Comment: Thank you a lot !!